# convert "1h30min" string to minutes in python

Tags: python, pandas

is there a one/two liner way to convert a time period string like `"1h30min"` to `"90min"` in Python/Pandas?

Comment: Please define "like". Does it stop at hours and minutes? Or could there be days, weeks, years, ...? Could there be whitespace? Uppercase letters? Punctuation?

Comment: How far will it deviate from that format? Will it always be "XhYmin"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Common guys it's too boring, let's make it a little bit more challenging:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

def humantime2minutes(s):
    d = {
      'w':      7*24*60,
      'week':   7*24*60,
      'weeks':  7*24*60,
      'd':      24*60,
      'day':    24*60,
      'days':   24*60,
      'h':      60,
      'hr':     60,
      'hour':   60,
      'hours':  60,
    }
    mult_items = defaultdict(lambda: 1).copy()
    mult_items.update(d)

    parts = re.search(r'^(\d+)([^\d]*)', s.lower().replace(' ', ''))
    if parts:
        return int(parts.group(1)) * mult_items[parts.group(2)] + humantime2minutes(re.sub(r'^(\d+)([^\d]*)', '', s.lower()))
    else:
        return 0

print(humantime2minutes('1 week 3 days 1 hour 30 min'))
print(humantime2minutes('2h1m'))
```

Output:

```
14490
121
```

Now seriously, there is a [pandas.Timedelta()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html):

```
print( pd.Timedelta('1h30min') )
```

Output:

```
0 days 01:30:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Very simple.  Just split by the `"h"` and convert:

```
hour, minute = "1h30min".split("h")
minutes = (60 * int(hour)) + int(minute.strip("min"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `format`:

```
import pandas as pd

s ="1h30min"

s = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%Hh%Mmin')
print s
1900-01-01 01:30:00

print type(s)
<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>

print s.hour * 60 + s.minute
90

print str(s.hour * 60 + s.minute) + 'min'
90min
```

Another [formats](http://strftime.org/).